# How can I trigger a function when a user registers in django?

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-registration

I took over a django web app and am still relatively new to django. I want to trigger a function whenever a new user registers on the website. But there is no code in the project to process the user registration. It all seems to happen under the hood. So I don't know where could put such a function call. The web app uses `django.contrib.auth`.

Additionally: How can I trigger a function when an account is activated?

Comment: django's [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#post-save) signal is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the signals to trigger an event when you save anything in your db, include the User from auth. You can see [the django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/) about this.
In your case, I think that the best way is like:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import user


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def user_saved(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    ...
```

In the kwargs you can see, for example, if object is created or modified. The sender is the Class and the instance is the object.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.